# select items/rows after a certain Id

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list of items (linq to sql), which can be ordered by various properties, **not just** by `Id asc/desc`

If the list was ordered only by `Id`,
I could call `list.Where(o => o.Id > 123).Take(10)`

is there any linq methods/functionality that would allow to ?

> Take 10 items after id with value = 123

Comment: `list.Where(...).OrderBy(o => o.Id).ThenBy(o => o.OtherProp).Take(10)`

Comment: id is unique so if I orderBy Id first, after it ordering ThenBy other properties makes no difference

Comment: Okay, just replace `Id` by another property to implement *"can be ordered by various properties"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has no concept of row ordering so it you can't request after a particular row from SQL. However, LINQ to Objects does so you can use that:

If `list` is a `List<T>` created from your query, just use `SkipWhile`:

```
list.SkipWhile(o => o.Id != 123).Skip(1).Take(10)
```

If `list` is a LINQ to SQL Query, then first use `AsEnumerable` but realize this will bring over the entire query to the client:

```
list.AsEnumerable().SkipWhile(o => i.Id != 123).Skip(1).Take(10)
```

If you know the ordering and can test against it, you could filter and reduce the amount of data returned to the client by 1. Computing the maximum duplicates of the ordering for a given `Id` and 2. Only returning the records in the desired order that are greater than or equal to the sort value(s) for the desired `Id`:

```
var maxdup = list.GroupBy(o => o.someProp).Select(og => og.Count()).Max();
var ans = list.Orderby(o => o.someProp)
              .Where(o => o.someProp >= list.Where(o2 => o2.Id == 123).First().someProp)
              .Take(10+maxdup)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .SkipWhile(o => o.Id != 123).Skip(1)
              .Take(10);
```